Export dynamic module with ts and Vite
I am new to typescript and Vite, but am trying to replicate some logic I had in an old project. However, with my new stack, require() and module.exports are no longer supported, so I'm trying to find the right way to do this.
My situation:
I have a folder where I keep my reusable Vue3 components, like buttons, input fields, etc. When I want to use those in any of my .vue files, I want to be able to call it like this:
import { MyButton, MyInput } from '@/components/my-components'

In order to do this, in the my-components folder, I have an index.ts, where I want to export all .Vue files from the src folder. So far, I created this:
const modules: Record<string, any> = import.meta.glob('./src/*.vue', { eager: true })

const exportData: Record<string, any> = {};
Object.keys(modules).forEach(component => {
  const name: string = modules[component].default.__name
  exportData[name] = modules[component].default
})

export default exportData


However, if I do this, I get this error:
SyntaxError: The requested module [...] doesn't provide an export named: MyButton

I noticed that if I change it to this, it works as expected, but that way it is no longer dynamic:
import MyButton from './src/MyButton.vue'
import MyInput from './src/MyInput.vue'

export {
  MyButton,
  MyInput,
}

If in my dynamic script I remove the "default" in "export default", I get different errors again.
Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

You can't provide named exports dynamically. And you'll have to additionally destructure default import to access  MyButton. Just don't do this, it won't play well with TS and ESM in general. The short syntax is export {default as MyButton} from './src/MyButton.vue'. Every reasonable third-party lib does that
